# How can I delete the empty textbox in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove the box that says edit inside, so I can move the widget on the side to the centre of the block. I have tried to delete the box on the main page but the text box is empty.

How can I delete the whole box so the widget moves along?

I have attached an image which shows the box with the edit link.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm very sure this is happening only when you're logged in as admin or editor.

Try and Log-out – the only one that can see the “edit” are logged in users that have the rights to edit the Page or Post.

additionally you can remove it via css `display: none;` property, if you have the class name or id of the element

Comment: I am the admin of the page. Thank you I managed to remove the box via css, but the widget on the side does not move along, how can I move the widget so it fills the space where the box was?

Comment: can you drop the website url and if possible the the exact location? so i can be able to assist further

Comment: though this is not the best approach to this, you could just use a custom post type rather in the best approach. but for the sake of this thread and the title of the question, use this if possible in the current page css file else it will affect others, `.secondary-sidebar {
    width: 100%;
}`